# How to declare dependencies for a specific Jar Maven publication in a Gradle project?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to publish a client library for my java API.

I declared a source subset in gradle for it, including domain classes and the client.

Now I'm trying to declare `spring-webflux` as a dependency so consumers of this client library can get it as a transitive dependency. I'm not being able to get this part working as no transitive dependencies are being declared in the published pom. I'm publishing this to a maven repository.

This is a simplified version of what i'm trying:

build.gradle

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'maven-publish'
}

group = 'test.publishing'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

sourceSets {
  client {
    compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
    compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
    java {
      source sourceSets.main.java
      include 'client/**'
    }
  }
}
  
configurations {
  clientApi {
    canBeConsumed = true
    canBeResolved = false
    attributes {
      attribute(Category.CATEGORY_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(Category, Category.LIBRARY))
      attribute(Usage.USAGE_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(Usage, Usage.JAVA_API))
      attribute(Bundling.BUNDLING_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(Bundling, Bundling.EXTERNAL))
      attribute(TargetJvmVersion.TARGET_JVM_VERSION_ATTRIBUTE, JavaVersion.current().majorVersion.toInteger())
      attribute(LibraryElements.LIBRARY_ELEMENTS_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(LibraryElements, 'jar'))
    }
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  clientApi 'org.springframework:spring-webflux:5.3.18'
}

task clientJar(type: Jar) {
  archiveBaseName = "client"
  from sourceSets.client.output
}

artifacts {
  clientApi clientJar
}

publishing {
  publications {
    mavenClient(MavenPublication) {
      artifactId = "client"
      groupId = "test"
      version = "1"
      artifact clientJar
    }
  }
}
```

My final goal is to have consumers of the `mavenClient` publication get the dependencies declared as `clientApi` as transitive dependencies.

If I build this sample project this is what I get in the generated POM:

```
$ ./gradlew clean publishToMavenLocal

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 366ms
7 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 1 up-to-date

$ cat build/publications/mavenClient/pom-default.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>client</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
</project>
```

When I consume from any other project I ahve to manually add a dependency for `spring-webflux`.

I'll be happy to share any other details to anyone willing to help me with this :)

Answer (score 0):

As it stands - the dependency is not linked to publication artefact as  runtime dependency.

There are multiple ways to try to link

1. replace `dependencies { clientApi .. }` with `dependencies { runtimeOnly .. }`
2. `configurations { runtimeClasspath extendsFrom clientApi }`
3. see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/component_capabilities.html#sec:declaring-additional-capabilities-for-a-local-component

you have to try out.

Comment: Hey! thanks a lot! Unfortunately, none of them worked for me